# Using RPM packages vs. Managing Dependencies with requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, puppet, dependency-management

I have a current project in which I am looking to build using multiple packages. I've had great experiences in the past with Java/Maven and PHP/composer, but, I've recently gotten into python with a new gig and I'm unaware of the "python" way doing dependency management. I've been reading up on using pip with a requirements.txt file and also using a setup module to hold your dependencies. I'm not really impressed by the use of txt files, but, thats another discussion.

It was suggested to build rpm packages from python modules and have puppet manage them in our environments. I'm curious what the pros & cons are for doing dependency management this way vs. managing dependencies in a main repository using pip.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, in my opinion at least, using a platforms own package management tools is the way to go. it's consistency, things are going to be the same no matter where you install the rpm. Secondly, puppet is a great tool for something like this. You can apply a manifest to x number of nodes and expect the same outcome across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet is indeed a great tool for managing dependencies. Personally, I have found building RPMs from Python modules to be something of a PITA. Puppet's `package` type actually has [support for the pip provider](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package-provider-pip).

Here's a puppet class that will install a couple of sample packages from pip (dependent on the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) being installed to install `python-pip` via `yum`):

```
class pip_modules {
    package { "python-pip":
        ensure => installed,
    }
    $pip_packages = [
        "requests",
        "simplejson"
    ]
    package { $pip_packages:
        ensure => installed,
        provider => pip,
        require => Package["python-pip"]
    }
}
```

I still haven't made up my mind whether this is a better idea than `requirements.txt`, which is potentially a more pythonic way of specifying requirements. It's certainly easier to run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to update the dependencies, but then you have to execute `pip install -r requirements.txt` at some point, perhaps via a puppet `exec`.

In terms of a winner, I generally go with the above option due to the extra effort involved (in my opinion) in building and managing RPMs, although there is much merit with the point of view that native packages (i.e. RPMs) are the way to go. That being said, pip/puppet are OS-independent, so if you have a need to install on multiple OSes then avoiding RPMs will avoid you having to produce `.deb` or other files.